# closure or another global function?

Tags: javascript

Which solution is better (according to best practices, performance..)?

A) Two global functions

```
    var optDatePart = function optDatePart(num)
    {
        var num = Math.abs(num);
        return (num < 10 ? "0" : "") + num;
    };

    var getFormattedDate = function getFormattedDate()
    {
        var date = new Date();
        return date.getFullYear() + "-" +
                optDatePart(date.getDate()) + "-" +
                optDatePart(date.getMonth() + 1) + " " +
                optDatePart(date.getHours()) + ":" +
                optDatePart(date.getMinutes());
    };
```

B) Closure

```
var getFormattedDate = (function()
{
    var optDatePart = function optDatePart(num)
    {
        var num = Math.abs(num);
        return (num < 10 ? "0" : "") + num;
    };

    return function getFormattedDate()
    {
        var date = new Date();
        return date.getFullYear() + "-" +
                optDatePart(date.getDate()) + "-" +
                optDatePart(date.getMonth() + 1) + " " +
                optDatePart(date.getHours()) + ":" +
                optDatePart(date.getMinutes());
    };

}) ();
```

First function is used only in second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. Why bother with the outer IIFE?

If the first function is used only in the second, just put one inside the other:

```
function getFormattedDate()
{
    function optDatePart(num)
    {
        var num = Math.abs(num);
        return (num < 10 ? "0" : "") + num;
    };

    var date = new Date();
    return date.getFullYear() + "-" +
            optDatePart(date.getDate()) + "-" +
            optDatePart(date.getMonth() + 1) + " " +
            optDatePart(date.getHours()) + ":" +
            optDatePart(date.getMinutes());
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that, it's almost night =)

Comment: Ehh... do you think that declaring inner function every time when its parent is called, is more effective than closure?

Comment: @Benji Depends on how often this is called. In the vast, *vast* majority of cases, yes, this is better than a more complex "faster" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Closures are almost always preferred over muddying up the global namespace (i.e. collisions).